# style="width:100%" is stretching the containing div. I don't want it to

Tags: html, css

My real project isn't using embedded styling or background colours. Those have been added for troubleshooting purposes only.

Starting with the code below, everything is fine, except the second text input feels a bit short. All the other text inputs stretch to fill the browser window. I don't want it to do that, but I would like it just to fill the section I coloured in red. So stretch all the way to the right, but not all the way to the left.

```html
<label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone</label>
<div style="background:blue;">
 <div style="background:yellow; float:left;">(<input style="width:20px;" type="tel" name="ext" id="phoneNumberExt" autocomplete="tel">)</div>
 <div style="background:red;"><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phoneNumber" autocomplete="tel"></div>
</div>
```

Given that I would like the text input to fill 100% of the parent div (i.e. area in red), my first instinct is to write `style="width:100%;"` but this does not have the desired result. See below.

```html
<label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone</label>
<div style="background:blue;">
 <div style="background:yellow; float:left;">(<input style="width:20px;" type="tel" name="ext" id="phoneNumberExt" autocomplete="tel">)</div>
 <div style="background:red;"><input style="width:100%;" type="tel" name="phone" id="phoneNumber" autocomplete="tel"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make the text input fill the area shown in red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flex` like below.

Add `display: flex` on parent div, and `flex: 1 0 auto;` on the second input's parent div and width 100% on the second input.

```html
<label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone</label>
<div style="background: :blue; display: flex;">
  <div style="background:yellow;;">(<input style="width:20px;" type="tel" name="ext" id="phoneNumberExt" autocomplete="tel">)</div>
  <div style="background:red;flex: 1 0 auto;">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phoneNumber" autocomplete="tel" style="    width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see I will need to spend some time studying this code to understand it, but it definitely gets the desired result. I even played with the browser width to see if I could break it. I couldn't. Good job.

Comment: You'll be happy to know, I just implemented your solution and it worked perfectly. (After I sorted out a few more bugs in my code.) It was also surprisingly hard to find a good article explaining what `"flex: 1 0 auto;"` does, but [this](https://devhints.io/css-flexbox) one wasn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to do like this:

```html
<div style="float:left;">
    <label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone</label>
 <div style="background:yellow; ">(<input style="width:20px;" type="tel" name="ext" id="phoneNumberExt" autocomplete="tel">)
 <input style="width:70%;" type="tel" name="phone" id="phoneNumber" autocomplete="tel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code you have given `width:20px;` to a div(yellow), so the remaining space in the parent div(blue) is **not 100%** therefore when you give width:100% to the input inside div(red) it breaks down and comes to the next line to take the 100%; width. Therefore **give width less than 100%;**

For your understanding I have updated the width, check the following code.

```html
<label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone</label>
<div style="background: :blue;">
  <div style="background:yellow; float:left;">(<input style="width:20px;" type="tel" name="ext" id="phoneNumberExt" autocomplete="tel">)</div>
  <div style="background:red;"><input style="width:94%;" type="tel" name="phone" id="phoneNumber" autocomplete="tel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand this, but I need it to display correctly for all browser widths.

Comment: use display type flex; for details on it. feel free to comment, I will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone</label>
<div style="background: :blue;width:100%;">
  <div style="background:yellow; float:left;width: 7%;">(
  <input style="width:20px;" type="tel" name="ext" id="phoneNumberExt" autocomplete="tel">)
  </div>
  <div style="background:red;float: right;width: 93%;">
    <input  type="tel" name="phone" id="phoneNumber" autocomplete="tel" style="    width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```